# A-frame Offline / Local Host Mode CORS Error

Tags: cors, localhost, offline, aframe

I need to use A-frame on offline with Google Chrome. Is it necessary to use a server to avoid the images and videos CORS error? Is there another way to run my code without a localhost? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a server of some sorts (https://aframe.io/docs/0.5.0/introduction/getting-started.html). Either local or using a service like `https://glitch.me`.

Comment: Thank You @ngokevin! What would you recommend us? We are trying to use A-frame in a educational project, some schools don’t have a internet connection and is necessary to use Chrome. Is there any other chance?

Comment: Usually we distribute the content on CDs/USBs because some schools don't have internet access on some geographical zones and we want share 360 experiences to that students.

Comment: Local servers can still be run offline. The docs give you examples such as `mongoose.exe`. Then hit like `localhost:8000` or whatever port the server is running on. It's not ideal though since it is web tech.